# TextBox to PasswordBox in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have to convert `TextBox` XAML to `PasswordBox` XAML. The main problem is  `<TextBox.Text>`.

Any clue how it can be done?

Thank you!

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="tbxPassword" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277">
 <TextBox.Text>
     <Binding Path="Password" Source="{StaticResource ods}"  UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
            <c:ConfigValidationRule />
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
     </Binding>
 </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If its really about password, you should use PasswordBox, Binding it to a dependency property would cause security vulnerabilities.

```
<PasswordBox
 Name="pwdBox" 
 MaxLength="64"
 PasswordChar="#"
 PasswordChanged="PasswordChangedHandler"  
/>
```

You can see the basic usage here
[Password Box](http://wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html)